# Adding monaco editor in devops work items extension

Tags: monaco-editor, azure-devops-extensions

we try to use monaco editor ([diff editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#creating-the-diffeditor-hello-diff-world)) in order to compare devops work items version in 2 different history point in time (with REST API `asOf` parameter).

we have a proof of concept working on laptop and standalone html page but we would like to embded it as an devops extension.

I can't find guidance (*I'm new to devops extension*) on how to achieve this, especially that monaco editor is already available.

I found references to `VSS/Features/Monaco`, tried to use it without luck.

```
    VSS.init();

    VSS.require(["VSS/Features/Monaco"], function (monaco) {
        var diffEditor = monaco.editor.createDiffEditor(document.getElementById('editor'), {
                    enableSplitViewResizing: false
                });   
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Where did you find reference `VSS/Features/Monaco`?

Comment: found it when trying to understand how monaco editor was loaded for repositories.

https://cdn.vsassets.io/ext/ms.vss-features/monaco-editor/ms.vss-features.monaco-editor.es6.EOSmRMqENx026Ee0.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reference `VSS/Features/Monaco` in DevOps. Since monaco provide [api](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.editor.html), you may call the monaco api in the js:

https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.editor.html#creatediffeditor

[image]

Comment: if I understand correctly, I would have to make the full loading myself ? there isn't "shortcut" by reusing existing monaco editor assets in devops ?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no "shortcut" as DevOps doesn't support this by default.

Comment: ok, clear enough :) wanted to be sure not to re-invent the wheel.